# is it valid for a subscribe callback function to make use of a computed observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have made this jsfiddle to illustrate a problem I am having:

http://jsfiddle.net/gt8d2mub/

```
var model = {
    a: ko.observable(false),
    b: ko.observable(false),
    c: ko.observable(false),
    data: ko.observable(''),
    isValid: function () {
        return this.a() && this.b() && this.c();
    }
};

model.allTrue = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.a() && this.b() && this.c();
}, model);

model.query = ko.computed(function () {
    return 'a = ' + this.a() + '; b = ' + this.b() + '; c = ' + this.c() + ';';
}, model);

model.query.subscribe(function () {
    if (this.isValid()) {
        // load some data...  
        this.data(this.query());
    }
    else {        
        this.data('no value'); 
    } 
}, model);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The model has three boolean observables; a, b and c.
A computed observable (allTrue) calculates if they are all true.
Another computed observable (query) is a summary of a, b, and c.

If I manually subscribe to "query" with the intention of loading some data, but first check "allTrue", "allTrue" may not yet be updated and correct, because the procedure to update its value happens after the callback fires.

For example, check a, then b, then c and the callback is called before the computed "allTrue" is calculated.

**Is what I am trying to do abnormal, or is there a way to get it to work?**

Perhaps there is no advantage to using a computed, and indeed, if I replace it with a normal function (isValid) I get the behaviour I expect. But I intend to have other things react to the allTrue/isValid value, and I thought I would usually use a computed in such scenarios (a normal function would also work, but I thought there would usually be advantages to using a computed there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `query` isn't valid unless all terms are available, it's probably better to push that evaluation into the `query` observable to tighten up the dependencies:

http://jsfiddle.net/gt8d2mub/1/

```
var model = {
    a: ko.observable(false),
    b: ko.observable(false),
    c: ko.observable(false),
    data: ko.observable('')
};

model.allTrue = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.a() && this.b() && this.c();
}, model);

model.query = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.allTrue() ? 
        'a = ' + this.a() + '; b = ' + this.b() + '; c = ' + this.c() + ';' 
      : null;
}, model);

model.query.subscribe(function (query) {
    if (!query) {
        this.data('no value'); 
        return;
    }
    // load some data...
    this.data(query);    
}, model);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Comment: Thanks. Query is still valid in my case. It just won't be used to load a set of data, unless all terms are true. It will be used for other things, regardless.

Comment: OK, then leave `query` the way it was and create a new `dataQuery` observable that you subscribe to and does this. The idea is that what you subscribe to should be doing your dependent observable checks.

Comment: "what you subscribe to should be doing your dependent observable checks" is the phrase that helped me understand. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you would need to use a manual subscription.  If you're not going to allow writing to the `data` property, you might as well make it computed.

```
model.data = ko.computed(function () {
    if (this.allTrue()) {
        return this.query();
    }
    else {
        return 'no value';
    }
}, model);
```

Comment: I have simplified my example, but in real life I want to make a request to the server. When the parameters change, I reload some data. Are manual subscriptions okay in that case?

Comment: A subscription would be fine if you've got async stuff you want to put into an observable.  People have come up with a few different ways of making async observables.  Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=async+computed will lead you to a few useful places, a good one to start with is: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/asynchronous-dependent-observables